# How To add datetime into sql by python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on a raspberry project which adds variables into a sqlite database

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO EntryLog(EntryTime)VALUES(?)",(time)
```

to make this work how can I make put current datetime value into time? (EntryTime is DATETIME value in sql, I need date and time in the same column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format time as string in format Y-m-d like `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

```
from datetime import datetime

time=datetime.now()
curs.execute("INSERT INTO EntryLog(EntryTime)VALUES(?)",(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: @Mert Yalcin you need to import the module datetime. If you use 'from datetime import datetime' you can do it as it is in the answer. If you just use 'import datetime' you will need to do 'time=datetime.datetime.now()'

Comment: @Mert Yalcin So you can upvote my answer and accept it

Comment: Why did you choose this one from the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)?